# Absolute child respect parents percentage based padding while pinning it to the bottom

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have an parent element which is relatively positioned. This element contains a child which is only partly visible. When the parent is hovered, the child should grow, to a maximum of 90% of the parent.

The parent has a static height and a padding in percentage.
Because the child needs to grow from the bottom up, it is positioned absolute, bottom 0.

Because the child is now positioned absolute, it does not respect the padding.
I've tried to solve it by adding a `left: 3%` and `right: 3%` to this child.
But I think these percentages aren't calculated against it's parent element because of the absolute positioning.

**The problem:**

[image: Problem]

**Desired result:**

[image: Desired result]

How can I grow this child element from the bottom up to a maximum of 260px while respecting the parents padding?

(I've tried using a margin-top approach but this has the undesired effect that the text always grew to the max size allowed, even when the text didn't need such amount of space.)

---

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.padding {
  padding: 3%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 286px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px white solid;
  float: left;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1.5%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  left: 3%;
  right: 3%;
  bottom: 0;
  max-height: 78px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-duration: .6s;
}
.padding:hover .absolute {
  max-height: 260px;
}
```

```html
<div class="padding" style="width: 70%">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  <div class="absolute">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
    Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
    Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.</div>
</div>
<div class="padding" style="width: 30%">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  <div class="absolute">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
    Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
    Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.</div>
</div>
<div class="padding" style="width: 100%">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  <div class="absolute">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
    eu, pretium quis, sem.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `div` containing all the contents of the `.padding` including the `.absolute`, then add these css to the `div` -

```
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

now this `div` will obey the `padding` applied to the `padding div` and hence the containing `div.absolute` will also. In this case you can remove the `padding-bottom` of the `div.padding` so that the `div.absolute` is positioned exactly down in the `div.padding`.
here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zm9qoaec/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a containing div with `.absolute` as a child. The containing div will be the one to respect the padding of `.padding`.

In this example: https://jsfiddle.net/42u1hac0/

```
.inner{
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

`overflow: hidden;` so that `.absolute` in its hovered state respects `.padding`'s padding.